# AWS ELB not picking up autoscaled instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, autoscaling

my aws auto-scaled instances are not picked up by load-balancer and the auto-scaled instances are recreated frequently,

also is there any problem in using auto-scaled instances and static instances at the same time in aws ELB ?
what are the precautions to take when doing so if it is possible 
is there any disadvantages doing so ?

Comment: Can you share your autoscaling configuration commands - in particular your launch configuration, your autoscaling group configuration, and the policies and I can answer the first part of the question.

Comment: I've created launch configuration using ezautoscaling,
How should i configure things accordingly what i need is to create a new instance when the autoscaled instance reach 80% cpu utilization for 5 mins and to scale down the instances when cpu utilization becomes less than 40%

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to make sure that your autoscaling group is registered with the load balancer appropriately, and that you have the appropriate policies.  Really need more details to answer this though.
2. Don't do it.  If you need an instance to be running all the time, configure your group to have a minimum of the number of "static" instances.  If you need to run a "static" instance, and a scaling group - you're probably thinking about the problem the wrong way.

Comment: What i need is i want to put an instance behind the ELB  that will be my master instance and if it is overloaded i want the load to be redirected to my autoscaled instance which is also put behind the ELB so that when the load increases, i want my ELB to distribute it to the master instance and autoscaled instance and further when it is over loaded the autoscaled instance should scale up. this is what i'm thinking of.

Comment: and also i'm afraid to put the autoscaled instance alone in the elb since we have live data and what happens if the autoscaled instance didn't work well as expected ? so thats why as a precaution i want to keep a static instance also in the ELB..!

Comment: Then set your minimum for your auto scaled instance to two.  It will ensure that here are always at least two instances available.  You're over thinking it.  Stop thinking traditional, start thinking cloud.  Expect your instances to fail at some point, and ensure that your scaling groups and ELB can handle it.  Otherwise, you may as well host in a traditional site and manage all that your self.

Comment: In that case what happens if the auto-scaled instance failed? It has happened for me, that's why i'm placing a static instance along with it. Is there any problem using autoscaled and static together with the ELB

Comment: if the autoscaled instance fails - the scaling group will replace it with a new healthy instance.

Comment: I know that .. but why is it failing .. why my autoscaled instances are not healthy ?
actualy they are healthy if i move them out from the LB. 
when i put it back to LB again healthy..

Comment: What is your elb health check set to?  Is it responding?  There are two types of health - instance running (scaling group health) and server responding (elb healthcheck).  Both need to be healthy.

Answer (score 0):

1. One reason could be: If you have configured your autoscaling group for multiple availability zones, but those zones are not added to the associated load balancer. In Management Console, go to **Load Balancers** -> **Instances** and verify **Availability Zones**.
2. I would go with @Peter H. Modify your design so you don't depend on any particular instance for persistent data. Store persistent data externally in a database or on S3.